# I can't set mysql pdo driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, driver

I'm trying to connect php to my MySQL databse, but I've a "could not find driver" message.
I'm working on Windows and I use php -s localhost:9000

This is the code I'm using to connect my database :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$port = "3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydb";
$dsn = "mysql:host=" . $servername . ";port=" . $port . ";dbname=" . $dbname;

try {
    
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $retour["connected"] = true;
    $retour["message"] = "Connexion à la base de données réussie";
    
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    $retour["connected"] = false;
    $retour["message"] = "Erreur lors de la tentative de connexion";
} ?>
```

Just to be sure, $dbname should be my MySQL schema's name, right ?

About the missing driver, I've tried to those things:

- Uuncomment extension_dir="ext" on both lines in my php.ini.
- Same for extension=pdo_mysql.
- php -v is giving me the same version I'm using.
- phpinfo() is giving me a "Configuration File (php.ini) Path =>  "
- I've tried to copy my php.ini at C:/Windows

I'm out of ideas. Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: "no driver" means that `pdo_mysql` is not available/installed/loaded.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. But how can i fix this ? I've tried so much things, i'm out of idea right now

Comment: This code won't give you anything like "could not find driver". But rather some "Erreur lors de la tentative de connexion"

Answer (score -1):

> In your browser, use localhost:3306 or localhost instead of localhost:9000.

Comment: My php server is running at localhost:9000, there is no problem with it. The problem is the connection to the database.